# Can't call non built-in function inside a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, parallel-processing

I have issue in my codes - there's a part in my codes make much calculations (30~40 seconds)

I need to reduce this time as much as possible - so I have to make 
use of my all CPU threads and distribute this part to be done more fast

for a few days - I made much researches and googled enough about how to write a multi-threaded code in nodejs , and I passed on many opinions about how nodejs is single threaded or multi-threaded , and readed about some topics like clustering , child-processes , and workers ..

I prefered to use a ready library to not dig into these topics too much ,
so I tried this library : https://github.com/Microsoft/napajs , but it fired some issues with me.

what I want should be simple - I just have array (ready for parallel computation - each thread ready to work on each element) 
 [data,data,data,data]

I found this library : https://www.npmjs.com/package/paralleljs a bit simple and has this method (map) which great for my case

let's move to my code

initializing

```
var p = new Parallel([54,25,66,23,14,27,15,18] , { maxWorkers : 8 });
```

3 functions (fun is the main function which call for exports.calc and calcc)

```
exports.calc = function(i,h)
{
    return Math.log2(i*h);
}

function calcc(i,h)
{
    return Math.log2(i*h);
}

function fun(h)
{
    var sum = 0;
   for (var i = 1 ; i < 55555 ; i++)
   {
       for (var l = 1 ; l < 55555 ; l++)
       {
           sum+=(exports.calc(i,l)); // in this case calc is not a function error
           sum+=(calcc(i,l)); // in this case calcc is not defined error
       }
   } 
   return sum;
}
```

starting the parallel calculations using map function -
this function should divide the array and let each thread to work on each element separately

```
p.map(fun).then(data => {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

the error always occurs in fun - anytime trying to call non built-in functions - for example

Math.max() , String.includes() and more ,, all these built-in functions are not making any issues , but any non built-in functions like calcc and exports.calc making issues

per the library docs , it uses the child processes - if this can help ,

if you can't help with this issue - but have other way to make this code possible (with any other libraries) - please share it

Comment: @estus , it's actually MCV example - I shared the all codes , you can test with it

Comment: I see. This obviously won't work for `map` because it passes a function to another process. This means that it stringifies it, so a function in child process is unaware of its original scope like `calcc`. This seems to be the limitation of Parallel that is "a simple library", as it says. You could try https://www.npmjs.com/package/paralleljs#requirestate to share common code. Or try Node's experimental workers instead

Comment: I'll try your suggestion npmjs.com/package/paralleljs#requirestate - unfortunately can't use workers - as my application is limited to version under node 10

Comment: @estus - yes solved , but it's a strange - the time in normal computation is X and as parallel is X*5 , the performance became too much bad

Comment: I would expect  that there's something wrong with Parallel implementation. It tries to cover both Node and browsers but seemingly doesn't do that well. I'm not aware of good multithread libs for Node and asking for them on SO is offtopic. Try Reddit. There's already Node clusters and you don't need to look any further if you're ok with its API. Node worker threads can likely be more efficient for this task but clusters are fine, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be implemented with Node [cluster](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html):

```
var cluster = require('cluster');

function calcc(i,h) {
    return Math.log2(i*h);
}

function fun(h) {
   var sum = 0;
   for (var i = 1 ; i < 5555 ; i++) {
       for (var l = 1 ; l < 5555 ; l++) {
           sum+=(calcc(i,l));
           sum+=(calcc(i,l));
       }
   } 
   return sum;
}

if (cluster.isMaster) {   
  var CPU = 8;    
  var count = 0;

  function messageHandler(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
    count++;
    if (count == CPU)
      console.log('Complete');
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < CPU; i++) {
    var worker = cluster.fork();
    worker.on('message', messageHandler);
  }    
} else if (cluster.isWorker) {
  process.send(fun());
}
```

Since a cluster is intended for network connections, it can provide some overhead, so low-level implementation with `child_process.fork()` (which is used by `cluster`) could be more efficient.

And there are experimental Node [worker threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) for Node 10 and higher.

Comment: I need to thanks you - for your answer , this really help

Answer (score 0):

Never used the parallel myself, but based on behaviour and how you use it, I suppose @estus is basically right.

If the function itself is passed -> it does not bring with itself any information about previous surroundings.

You will need to initialize at the function beginning everything you use.

Most direct way is to just put it inside main function:

```
function fun(h)
{
    const calc = function(){...}
}
```

The most elegant is to use require inside. So put everything you want to share into another module, export it and just do the

```
function fun(h)
{
    const tools = require('tools');
    tools.calc(...)
}
```

Comment: Yes - thanks for the solutions , but the library has a solution for it : https://www.npmjs.com/package/paralleljs#requirestate